# Host is not allowed to connect to this mysql database

Tags: c#, mysql, database, visual-studio-code

I'm making a web api chat application in ASP.NET Razor Pages in VS Code with SignalR and with MySQL database. (Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio)

I wanted to store the messages and the users in a table, but when I made the MySQL connection I got an error message:

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Host '' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server
```

It can cause, that I connected to the database before in **appsettings.json** file with ConnectionString?

Here is the **ChatHub.cs** code:

```html
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using probagetrequest.Models;

namespace SignalRChat.Hubs
{
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {

        public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
        {
            string connn = "Server=localhost;Database=DBChatApp;user id=sa;password=xxx";
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connn);
            try { 
            Console.WriteLine("Connecting to MySql...");
            con.Open();
            string cmddd = "INSERT INTO Messages (Username,Message) VALUES (@Usernamee,@Messagee)";
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(cmddd, con);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Usernamee", MySqlDbType.VarString).Value = user;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Messagee", MySqlDbType.VarString).Value = message;
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exc.ToString());
            }
            con.Close();
            Console.WriteLine("Done!!!!!");

            Console.WriteLine($"user={user}, message={message}");
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try logging into MySQL DB through mysql client CLI. I think it's a problem with "mysql user" privileges mentioned in your project to connect to the MySQL DB.

In general, the error you mentioned comes when a new database is setup but left un-configured.

Try the following commands logging into MySQL as super user

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'root';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: thank you for the help. where do I need to write this code? in VS code, SQL Server extension?